# Video Recording in a video call product

Tags: video, recording

I am currently working on a product which helps in providing the video call solution to the college administration.
But as a part of video call, video recording is mandatory for future audits.
Currently i am using jitsi for creating conference between the students and the admin user, and capturing the video and audio stream using media recorder api, but sometime the video has glitches in it, or audio is missing etc.

Is there a better way of video recording and also it is scalable, as there is an option of using jibri, but jibri requires lot of resources for the same.

Please help me out with this problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use options other than Jibri, there are other third-party paid APIs that abstract some of the WebRTC complexity and offer recording, like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/go/video-solution-sales-1?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%2Btwilio%20%2Bvideo&utm_campaign=G_S_NAMER_Brand_Twilio&gclid=CjwKCAjwj8eJBhA5EiwAg3z0m4CcDstWGJqYsCYFDL42TLc8v308ZRtP0m-I7oBDkfowLAQWwdo2ZhoCzR8QAvD_BwE), [Agora](https://www.agora.io/), or [Daily](https://www.daily.co/) (full disclosure: I work at Daily). I'm not sure if a paid product is an option, but I thought I'd list them just in case. Good luck!